# How to determine if an ad is showing using the adwords api

Tags: google-ads-api

The adwords UI has a nice "Ad showing now?" dialog that says if an ad is showing or not, and in the case the ad isn't showing has a little message explaining why.

Is there a way to programmatically access this information directly on the ad?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no direct way, how to see **exactly the same** information as in web interface.

However, through API, you can download:

*Keywords Approval Status*

(https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/keywords)

and Ad status - *CreativeApprovalStatus*
(https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/ad-performance-report)

and maybe for ex. no. of impressions to each, and since you can download this up to 1000x a day (I would recommend less), you shall have **less precise, but similar information as well.**

*API usage & limitations:* https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/ratesheet